# Php add class dynamically to the first and last block

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this

```
$products_array = array('test product', 'test new product', 'test lipsum', 'test lorem',  ....);
```

I just got the values from array like this

```
echo '<ul>';
foreach( $products_array as $product_array ) {
    echo '<li>$product_array</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

But here I want something dynamic. I want to add class name according to the value set by the user. Lets say user wants to show 5 lists in a row then the markup will be like this

```
<ul>
    <li class="first">test product</li>
    <li>test new product</li>
    <li>test lipsum</li>
    <li>test lorem</li>
    <li class="last">test update</li>
    <li class="first">test new product</li>
    <li>test a product</li>
    <li>test new lipsum</li>
    <li>test lorem</li>
    <li class="last">test new update</li>   
 </ul>
```

So here you can see at last means after each 5 post its adding class last and it is adding class first to the first list and after the fifith list blocks. So in this when user will set $class = 3 then it will add last class to the third block and the first will be added to the first and the list block just after the 3rd, 6th, 9th etc

I have done like this

```
$last = '4' //set 4. so for 4th,8th,12th it will add class last. and for 1st, 5th, 9th it will add class first

 echo '<ul>';
 $i = 0;
 $count = count($products_array);
foreach( $products_array as $product_array ) {
$i++;
$class = '';
if( $i == $count ) {
$class = 'last';
}
    echo '<li class='.$class.'>$product_array</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

But its not working. So can somone tell me how to do this? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: You want the [modulus operator](http://php.net/manual/language.operators.arithmetic.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a modulus to determine the class to add. The logic goes...

1. When the remainder is 0, we are on the last item of each group (the *nth* of *n*)
2. When the remainder is 1, we are on the first item of each group (the *1st* of *n*)
3. Otherwise, we are somewhere in the middle

For example

```
$last = 4;
?>
<ul>
<?php
foreach ($products_array as $index => $product) :
switch(($index + 1) % $last) { // array indexes are 0-based so add 1
    case 0 :
        $class = 'last';
        break;
    case 1 :
        $class = 'first';
        break;
    default :
        $class = '';
}
?>
<li class="<?= $class ?>"><?= htmlspecialchars($product) ?></li>
<?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

[eval.in demo](https://eval.in/421329)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. You could also use modulus, but i am not quite sure how it behaves with small perPage-settings.

```
//your perPage-setting, change this for more elements per page
$perPage = 3;
$count = count($products_array);
//loop over elements
for($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
    $className = "";
    if($i / $perPage == 0) {
        $className = "last";
    } else if((floor($i / $perPage) * $perPage + 1 == $i)
        $className = "first";
    echo '<li class='.$className.'>'.$product_array[$i-1].'</li>';
}
```